# Still can't get the original height of an HTML element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem where I have an element like

```
div#myElement
{
    height: 600px;
}
```

and in my JavaScript I need to get the value `600` (so that it's not a magic number floating around many places of my code). When call that `$("#myElement').height()` I get a decimal, something like `599.something`. Someone suggested that I instead use `$('#myElement').css('height')`. When I did that, it still returned a decimal value. Click here http://jaminweb.com/snake_TEST_PHP.php and see the `alert` that comes up. That's from the line

```
        var SH = $("#snakediv").css("height");
        alert(SH);
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see 600px in the alert box in chrome v.36

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: alerts 600px, on mac and chrome : http://help.dottoro.com/ljbixkkn.php

Comment: alerts 600px, on firefox

Comment: also in IE 9, Safari 5.1.7 and Firefox 30. I don't see an issue with getting correct value..

Comment: If you somehow in some browser get 599.99 (or nearly so), you can simply use `var SH = Math.round($("#snakediv").css("height"));`

Comment: I don't want to use rounding because I need the exact number 600. If, for some reason, it ever comes up as 599.49999 and rounds to 599, then my whole program screws up.

Comment: As mentioned below, you problem is the page zoom. Click Ctrl + 0, that should reset your zoom and give you the exact height you are looking for.

Comment: don't forget to protect your program from this if it will break it just by zooming!

Answer (score 7):

> I get a decimal, something like `599.something`

This is because you've zoomed your page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mousewheel). This means that pixels are being scaled, and the calculation to work out sizes has some error introduced, resulting in your almost-but-not-exactly value of e.g. `599.5454545021057` at `110%`.

Reset your zoom to 100% and you'll get the expected `600`